# Share Facebook Post via Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, facebook, facebook-messenger

Today I saw an interesting post on Facebook (App). So I decided to share it through **Whatsapp** with my friends. But I can't find any Whatsapp share button on **FB App**. There is only **Messenger** share button. So how I can share it through Whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

Click the post you want to share, in the top left hand corner there is a down arrow click it for options. You can copy the link and send from WhatsApp or if your keyboard has the option share it from the clipboard.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose you want to share a video, click on the video.
2. Once it starts playing, now 'right-click' on the playing video, you will see a drop-down like this: [image: Options on right-click on video]
3. Select the 'Show Video URL option, you will get the link. Copy and paste it into a new window to test if it opens up the desired FB post or not.. Thanks.!